# Binance stream timestamp ahead

Tags: python, timestamp, epoch, binance

I am trying to concile the timestamps I receive from Binance and mine in order to do some calculi but I cannot get passed the 1st issue : Binance time is 500ms in the future...

Here is my testing code (this is the on-message f that I call inside the websocket.WebSocketApp() :

```
        def on_message(ws, message):
            message= json.loads(message)
            print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ": ")
            tbinance = message['E'] 
            tmeth1 = int(time.time() * 1000)
            tmeth2 = time.time_ns() // 1000000
            tmeth3 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

            print('meth 1 : ' + str(tbinance - tmeth1))
            print('meth 2 : ' + str(tbinance - tmeth2))
            print('meth 2 : ' + str(tbinance - tmeth3))
```

I systemtically get around 500ms ahead for the binance stream:

```
        2023-03-24 11:00:17.349156: 
        meth 1 : 502
        meth 2 : 502
        meth 2 : 502
```

How can I sort this?
is my computer behind ? how do I reajust the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306172/time-difference-with-binance-server) you can see that it is probably caused by time the request takes to travel to the server.

I know the order of commands is different there, but it could still be the issue depending on if you system waits for the response before executing the rest of the code or continues and just waits for the time.

You can try to `ping` the server and see if it matches with the time difference that you get.

Alternatively you can do something like `time.sleep(.1)` in between all time related calls and see if you differences become `600`, `700` and `800`, which would indicate that there is an actual difference, or `400`, `300` and `200`, in that case it would be caused by travel time of the message.

Comment: Thank you. I would understand if the Binance stream took 500ms to reach me and that would explain the difference. What I don't understand is that the timestamp of the stream is ahead of me by 500ms which means it isthe future, or that I am late...
And that throws me off a bit

Comment: This is just a guess but what I think could be happening is the following: You request binance time -> the request is sent -> you retrieve your system time -> the request arrives at the server -> the response is sent. As I said I don't know for sure if that's what is happening. It would make sense from a performance point of view to not wait for a response before continuing with the code execution until the requested value is needed